# How to use RegisterType(Type).As(Type)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

My MVC project uses Autofac 3.0 and I want to `RegisterType` by reflection.
First defined one interface and implementation named like `IRegisterDemo` and `RegisterDemo` less parameters.
I tried to use `builder.RegisterType(typeof(RegisterDemo)).As(typeof(IRegisterDemo))` in my `Application_Start` method, it successed, but it's not my purpose.

I want to define one attribute like `UseAutofacAttribute` to reflect the types and use `RegisterType(ImplType).As(InterfaceType)`, when I wrote the code in `Application_Start`, it worked, so I built another project to do this further and referenced the project dll in my MVC project, and in `Application_Start` just run one static method, unfortunately it failed.

So I want to know the reason and how to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your registrations attribute based, I'd suggest you use [Autofac's MEF adapter](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mef/). It will let you decorate your types with the `ExportAttribute` and be picked up by your `ContainerBuilder`.

#### Example

```
[Export(typeof(IRegisterDemo))] // <-- This exports RegisterDemo as IRegisterDemo
public class RegisterDemo : IRegisterDemo { }

// Example method to register assemblies with ContainerBuilder
public void RegisterPartsFromReferencedAssemblies(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // Get referenced assemblies
    var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();

    // Create an AssemblyCatalog from each assembly
    var assemblyCatalogs = assemblies.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x));

    // Combine all AssemblyCatalogs into an AggregateCatalog
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(assemblyCatalogs);

    // Register the catalog with the ContainerBuilder
    builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog);
}
```

This example shows how to export a type and how to register referenced assemblies with the `ContainerBuilder`. You can then do `container.Resolve<IRegisterDemo>()` to get the exported part (or have it injected into a class).

**NOTE:** This will register exported parts from all referenced assemblies, including:

- Assemblies specified in the assemblies element of the Web.config file
- Assemblies built from custom code in the App_Code directory
- Assemblies in other top-level folders

Comment: Thank you very much, it's worked.
But in my Mvc site project, when I was in one controller, it throw System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
'
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private IRegisterDemo _demo;
        public AccountController(IRegisterDemo demo)
        {
            _demo= demo;
        }
'
by the way, I referenced Autofac,Autofac.Configuration,Autofac.Integration.Mvc,Autofac.Integration.Mef

Comment: And here is my code in global:
'
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            RegisterPartsFromReferencedAssemblies(builder);
            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
'

Comment: When you're using Autofac's MVC integration, you have to register the controllers with `builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(Global).Assembly);`...

Comment: Oh, I got it, Thank you very much, Thanks All again.

Comment: I got another problem: when I used ExportAttribute, I must build the interfaces and implementation into one project, but I want to separate them for 2 projects, is there any thing wrong in my intention?

Comment: No, that's perfectly reasonable. You just have to make sure that the project with the interface is referenced in the project with the implementation (which it has to be to compile :P). Why do you think they'd have to be in the same project?

Comment: I think this is out of this question's scope. If you can't find the info about how to export a part as an interface type from another assembly on SO, file another question :)